# logcat stops writing to file on device

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

For an android app I'm saving logs on the device itself so that when there are issues we can find out what they are. This device runs in a no internet environment so it's not an option to write the logs remotely.

The below code first clears the buffer, then continuously writes whatever is logged to 'logFile'.

```
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c"); // -c clear buffer.
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile + " -r 5120 -n 30"); // -r amount of bits to write, -n amount of logs to rotate
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This code works fine, except after some time, hours or days it randomly stops saving the log.

What might cause this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Im not an expert on this, but shouldnt you write out the contents of logcat, before clearing the buffer?

Comment: Thanks for the input Doomsknight. In this case it runs this code when starting the app, so I'm just throwing out everything that might've been left in there which should be about nothing. logcat keeps running after this command, so all log lines after this command are saved to a file (until it stops).

Comment: Ah i see, you have it logging in real time. Thought you were logging on startup, any previous errors. (hence then clearing once logged). Is it possible this should go in on resume or something? As maybe the OS is preventing background activity while minimized. Causing the process to be shut down but never resumed. Probably wrong, just throwing out some thoughts. :)

Comment: Good thoughts again Doomsknight. This is actually a 24/7 on kiosk application, that should never ever go to the background. I've logged 'onResume' to try and see if it is doing this someway but since the logging stops I can't find out if it actually doesn't get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the app used a browser which did javascript requests. Occassionally these requests failed, but they were never cleaned up because no response came. This specific app is on 24/7 meaning it doesn't get to clear these requests in the normal way. Because this browser is using it's own sandbox no errors are thrown when this happens but at some point the memory fills up causing it to have no memory left to continue logging. Hence the problem of no memory is not logged. The fix in this case was to clear and restart the in-app browser every 6 hours, which fixed the problem.

This only happened on a specific Siemens tablet with a specific Android build.

Comment: Sonja, I think I'm seeing something similar in an app I'm working with. Logcat files just stop being written to, although if I connect to the app in the debugger, I see fresh output to logcat in Android Studio. Can you tell me a little more about how you figured out the underlying cause? (Mine's happening a lot quicker than 6 hours, but the app doesn't crash or seem to misbehave. Still trying to figure out whether a silent failure is happening.)

Comment: @korinthe I can't remember the exact code from 2 years ago but there is a way to look at memory usage Android as a whole not just the sandbox your app is running in, as this is a different sandbox than the one the browser runs in. I found out the general memory usage kept slowly increasing until it was very high at the point the logging stopped. I also displayed the memory usage in the app so I could see that after the logging stopped the memory usage went back to normal. I didn't catch the exact time but about 10 minutes after.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check permissions first. Might you are testing the application in marshmallow and above. Please try the below code and let me know is it work for you:

```
    public class MyProjectApp extends Application {

    /**
     * Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
     */
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {

            File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyProjectAppFolder" );
            File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory + "/log" );
            File logFile = new File( logDirectory, "logcat" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt" );

            // create app folder
            if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
                appDirectory.mkdir();
            }

            // create log folder
            if ( !logDirectory.exists() ) {
                logDirectory.mkdir();
            }

            // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
            try {
                Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile);
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if ( isExternalStorageReadable() ) {
            // only readable
        } else {
            // not accessible
        }
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

you need the correct permissions in your .manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Source
source: http://www.journal.deviantdev.com/android-log-logcat-to-file-while-runtime/

Comment: Thanks for the idea Anupreet, the code surrounding my snippet is actually very much like you posted and all permissions are set correctly. The code runs fine for the first few hours, but after some random time (hours/days) it stops working, so it's definitely not a permissions problem. More likely something in Runtime stops working.